# Open Form based on ComboBox Access 2010

Tags: ms-access

I have a combobox on a form, with an unbound column [System Type]. I'm working in Access's Macro Builder, trying to setup an If statement. My end goal is to open a form, dependant on the unbound column.

I can't seem to figure out how to reference that column. I've tried [Forms]![My Form]![My Combo].Column(1), but I get an unrecognized function error. I've also tried variants of that statement from searches online.

How do I reference an unbound column in a combobox in the MacroBuilder in Access 2010 for an If statement?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a combo only has one column, it is column(0), or simply [MyCombo], I think you are missing that there are two types of bound with a combo, it can be bound to a field in a table and you can have a bound column, which is the value returned by the combo.

```
Row Source : SELECT Atext FROM ATable
Bound Column : 1
Column Count : 1

MsgBox Me.myCombo  ''Atext

Row Source : SELECT ID, Atext FROM ATable
Bound Column : 1
Column Count : 2

MsgBox Me.myCombo  ''ID
MsgBox Me.MyCombo.Column(1) ''Atext

Row Source : SELECT ID, Atext FROM ATable
Bound Column : 2
Column Count : 2

MsgBox Me.myCombo  ''atext
MsgBox Me.MyCombo.Column(0) ''ID
```

So to open a form from this form:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "aForm",,,"ID=" & Me.MyCombo ''First example
```

From another form

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "aForm",,,"ID=" & Forms!AnotherForm.MyCombo ''First example
DoCmd.OpenForm "aForm",,,"Atext='" _
   & Forms!AnotherForm.MyCombo.Column(1) ''Second example
```

Comment: I had the combo box setup similar to the second example. It seems my syntax was wrong. I was using, [Forms]![My Form]![School Combo].[Column](1) the correct was [Forms]![My Form].[School Combo].[Column](1). The difference being the ! between [My Form] and [School Combo] should be a .
Thanks for your help.